# C# Winform program freezing when calling Debug.WriteLine frequently in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

After I changed HDD to SSD, I run my development program with Debug mode in Visual Studio and program always freezing(not responding) but there is no problem before changing HDD.
I have tried to investigate the problem and found that Debug.WriteLine has related to the problem.

To repeat the problem, I give simple application below. After click the button, Output panel in Visual Studio will show text as expected but if we move cursor after click the button while text is showing the program will freeze.

Edit : If I uncomment Thread.Sleep(5); the program will not freeze.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void buttonTestRun_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Thread thread1 = new Thread(Worker);
        thread1.Start();
    }

    private void Worker()
    {
        int total = 10000;
        for (int i = 0; i < total; i++)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine($"Progress : {(double)i / total * 100}%");
            //Thread.Sleep(5);
        }
    }
}
```

I am using Windows 10 20H2 (19042.804), Visual Studio 2019 (16.8.6)

Could you please give me some suggestion ?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: *changed HDD to SSD*, then *Progress: ...%*. What do you actually have there, in your real code? Something that reads from files on disc and updates the UI, Invoking it?

Comment: In my real code, I have everything you mentioned. I saw a lot of messages in Output panel while running. 
However, The point is I also get freeze program when I have run simple application above. Some of my friend also get freeze program like me when run this code.

Comment: Not this code. Show your real code.

Comment: Since my code is more than thousand of lines and the problem randomly occurs. I have no idea what portion of code to show. That why I have tried to repeat the problem with simple program.

Comment: It's the code that (quite too often) Invokes the UI from that Thread you started.